# Create regularly-spaced vector points from irregular XY geographic data in Python

Tags: python, vector, coordinates, gis, qgis

I have point (vector) coordinates in meters (x and y in 1-D arrays) which are irregularly spaced. I would like to re-sample the points so that they are regularly spaced by 10 m between each set of XY points.

I have managed to regularly re-sample the points in the X direction (see code below), however when trying to use the scipy.interpolate.interp1d function on the Y variable, the points are obviously no longer spaced by 10 m. The code I use is as follows:

```
f_bot = interpolate.interp1d(x, y) 
xnew_bot = np.arange(np.min(x),np.max(x),10) # 10 m spaced
ynew_bot = f_bot(xnew_bot)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew_bot, ynew_bot,'-')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

If one measures the space between each orange point (in say, QGIS) or by doing:

```
dist_total = np.hstack([0,np.cumsum(np.hypot(np.diff(xnew_bot),np.diff(ynew_bot)))])
diff_dist = np.diff(dist_total) # calculate distance difference between each points
```

diff_dist will show that points are still irregularly spaced due to the interpolation of the Y points. Another way to see is to compute the distance between each X points, which is exactly 10 m, and compute the same for the Y points which show they are irregular.

Is there a function or approach I could use to make sure both X and Y are spaced regularly? All I need is that each set of X Y points is spaced apart by 10 m, which should be simple to do but I can't find a better way so far! Any help would be appreciated.

Data for X and Y are as follows:
| x | y |
| -------- | -------------- |
| -1091590.00|158697
| -1091580.00|158702
| -1091580.00|158708
| -1091570.00|158713
| -1091560.00|158719
| -1091550.00|158724
|...|...
| -1079450.00|164674
| -1079440.00|164677
| -1079430.00|164680
| -1079420.00|164683

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider

1. finding the interpolation line [ST_LineInterpolatePoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoints.html)
2. measure the length of the line [in meters], [ST_Length](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html)
3. divide it by 10 [m] to find number of slots,
4. divide the line by number of slots to find the coordinates for each group of points, [ST_LineSubstring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362096/how-to-create-line-substrings-with-fixed-lengths-from-a-line-ignoring-inflection)
5. divide number of points by number of slots and assign them to coordinates from p. 4 (you can find the distance between points and division coordinates with [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, these functions appear to be from PostGIS. Is there any function that can be readily used in Python without having to go through the hassle of connecting Python with PostGIS or QGIS with PostGIS and having to learn a whole new software?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to create evenly spaced points from interpolation using your original data points.
There's plenty of examples here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html
This is how you can use it, you have to specify `max_len`

```
from scipy import interpolate
f1 = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], max_len)
y_new = f1(x_new)
```