# How do I create a regularly spaced grid from irregular data that includes all the original data points? Is it even worth doing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have the data in the following way: an `x` array of longitudes, a `y` array of longitudes, and a `z` array of the rainfall at those latitudes and longitudes. I want to create a matrix to test different interpolation methods (many of which are not available by default in `scipy` or similar toolkits).  `x` and `y` are unevenly spaced but have the same length (i.e. some part of `x` has the following values: `34.9912, 35.1568, 35.8881` but later on `x` contains `46, 45, 47`). I want to create the coarsest possible regularly spaced matrix that contains each and every points. I have illustrated an example below:

Suppose `x=[36,38,31]`, `y=[12,19,15]`, and `z=[1,2,3]`. I want to create the following matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

where the positive values are located where the function takes values. How do I do this in Python or any other language? (I would prefer Python)

Someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70771182/create-regularly-spaced-vector-points-from-irregular-xy-geographic-data-in-pytho) and was told to do the following:

```
from scipy import interpolate
f1 = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], max_len)
y_new = f1(x_new)
```

however this doesn't work because it doesn't contain the original points. Also, `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` is going to be deprecated soon, so I'm looking for a more modern solution.

The above example is obviously a toy example with integer gaps. Since the real data contains points to the fourth decimal, I can foresee that I would need to make at least 10000 points just to move forward an integer, and this would very quickly get unwieldy when dealing with real data, which may, eventually, encompass the entire world. It's not storing the data but the interpolation which would take time, so I'm looking to reduce the computation time as much as possible.

However, I am not sure whether this is the best way to approach the problem. Examples on the internet suggest using `griddata` or something similar to generate a grid quickly. However this has the disadvantage of being unevenly spaced and creates simply a grid. Would using something like `linspace(x[0],x[-1],10000)` be the right approach? I foresee endless hours of waiting while I'm testing my interpolation if I end up using my proposed method and if it turns out that it could be done in an easier way, then I don't want to waste my time.

Edit 1: As suggested by @Reinderien, here is the histogram for the latitudes and longitudes:

[image: Latitudes]

[image: Longitudes]

Here are the histograms obtained by `np.diff(np.sort)`[image: Latitudes]

[image: Longitudes]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUBXB.png)

Edit 2: better binned plots for the second part[image][image]

Comment: What is the actual shape of your irregular grid?

Comment: @Reinderien I don't quite understand your question. My data is simply latitudes, longitudes, and the value at that latitude and longitude. My latitude array can be something like ``[36,37,38,50.0035,50.0062,50.0077]`` and the corresponding longitudes can vary in their own way. is that what you're asking?

Comment: You say you want the "coarsest possible regularly spaced matrix that contains each and every point." Considering you want every point, you would need to find a spacing that captures the smallest differences in x (e.g. if there are points 3.0001 and 3.0004 you'd need to space points 0.0003 apart) and still exactly match all the other points (which would be difficult if you also have an x point of 5, since that cannot be reached exactly with a 0.0003 spacing between points).

Comment: I mean, how many points do you have in each axis?

Comment: @Reinderien it depends on the area of the Earth I want to observe (for example, measurements across Austria give me ~10000 points (so 10k latitudes and 10k longitudes) but measurements across Sudan might top out at 50 points)

Comment: For a higher-quality answer, I recommend that you take realistic data, run an `np.diff(np.sort)` on your grid axes and post a histogram of the resulting PDF. Otherwise any advice we offer is basically conjecture.

Comment: @Reinderien added the plots.

Comment: You're probably going to need to choose different bins for the last two plots to be meaningful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it even worth doing?

That depends on a lot of things, including how many points you have, what precision you need and what memory impact you can sustain.

Fundamentally this is a GCD; producing the following axes:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([36, 38, 30])
y = np.array([12, 19, 15])
z = np.array([1, 2, 3])

xspace = np.gcd.reduce(np.diff(np.sort(x)))
yspace = np.gcd.reduce(np.diff(np.sort(y)))
xreg = np.arange(x.min(), x.max() + xspace, xspace)
yreg = np.arange(y.min(), y.max() + yspace, yspace)
print(xreg)
print(yreg)
```

```
[30 32 34 36 38]
[12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

The differential over both dimensions is fed into a GCD that gives you your coarsest spacing. Note that I've changed your input data to be "more interesting" so that `xspace` takes a value of 2; otherwise both of your example arrays have differentials for which the greatest common divisor is 1.

For floating-point values such as your `34.9912` you're going to need to multiply by your precision factor (1e4?) and coerce to an integer. The higher your precision factor, the more massive your regularized grid may become.

Comment: This solution touches on the issue I mentioned in my comment. If you actually have floats, then (1) gcd doesn't work on floats (at least not without your coercion suggestion) and (2) the `xspace`/`yspace` would need to be at least as small as the smallest value in `np.diff` to capture the finest differences between coordinates, which may make it impossible (depending on the desired precision) to capture all points (or it may be infeasible).

Comment: This seems like the most straightforward answer. I obviously will need to coerce but this generates the matrix I want.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is considering using Gaussian Process instead to generate a function that can predict values at arbitrary points, then generating the points from whatever grid you desire. The below example uses a default kernel which just dictates a generally smooth function. You'll have to do your own research on kernels if you want a certain behavior in the fitting.

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor

x = [36, 38, 31]
y = [12, 19, 15]
z = [1, 2, 3]

X = list(zip(y, x))

gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor().fit(X, z)

gridx = np.arange(-40, 40, 1)

grid = list(it.product(gridx, gridx))
pred = gpr.predict(grid)

img = np.array(pred).reshape((80, 80))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, extent = [-40, 40, 40, -40])
```

Comment: Is this the approach used in kriging? I have tried kriging and it produces smooth graphs but does not seem to retain the meso-scale information I want.

Comment: I have not heard the term before, but a quick search suggests they are the same thing. If it doesn't preserve the information you want, that could be an issue with what kernel you selected.